# Login Page not working correctly although the code is alright

Tags: html, css, authentication, admin

Recently, I got a login page created with HTML & CSS. The styling it contains in the css code is not being displayed in the result. I have gone through the whole code a couple of times, but it seems all good to me. It doesn't gives the result as it should be according to the css code. Kindly tell me what the real issue is? Whether it is the code? Or something else :)
Code:

```css
body {
    background: #222D32;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.login-box {
    margin-top: 75px;
    height: auto;
    background: #1A2226;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.login-key {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#27EF9F, #0DB8DE);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.login-title {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

.login-form {
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: #1A2226;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

input[type=password] {
    background-color: #1A2226;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    outline: 0px;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: inherit;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #1A2226;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.form-control-label {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #6C6C6C;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    border-color: #0DB8DE;
    color: #0DB8DE;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover {
    background-color: #0DB8DE;
    right: 0px;
}

.login-btm {
    float: left;
}

.login-button {
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.login-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: #A2A4A4;
}

.loginbttm {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 login-box">
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-key">
                    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    ADMIN PANEL
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">USERNAME</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12 loginbttm">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-text">
                                    <!-- Error Message -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-button">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">LOGIN</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag must be compared. you must add another  because on line 1 you started a new div without ending it.

fixed code:

```css
body {
    background: #222D32;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.login-box {
    margin-top: 75px;
    height: auto;
    background: #1A2226;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.login-key {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#27EF9F, #0DB8DE);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.login-title {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

.login-form {
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: #1A2226;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

input[type=password] {
    background-color: #1A2226;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    outline: 0px;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: inherit;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0DB8DE;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #1A2226;
    color: #ECF0F5;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.form-control-label {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #6C6C6C;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    border-color: #0DB8DE;
    color: #0DB8DE;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover {
    background-color: #0DB8DE;
    right: 0px;
}

.login-btm {
    float: left;
}

.login-button {
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.login-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: #A2A4A4;
}

.loginbttm {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 login-box">
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-key">
                    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    ADMIN PANEL
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">USERNAME</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12 loginbttm">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-text">
                                    <!-- Error Message -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-button">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">LOGIN</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

(I tested this before answering this question)